Sound is "Dummy Output" on `MacBookPro14,1` i.e. MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
How can I fix the "Dummy Output" problem on a 2017 MacBook Pro (Intel-based)? Currently, sound isn't working and I see "Dummy Output" as the output device when I attempt to increase (or decrease) the volume.
I found a similar question: Dummy Output and No Input devices on 2017 iMac Pro and the fix was using https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409 (Linux Kernel Sound Driver for Cirrus Logic CS8409 (e.g. for iMac27 5k)) which has 6 outstanding issues and hasn't been updated for 2 years.
There is also https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro (Kernel audio driver for Macs with 8409 HDA chip + MAX98706/SSM3515 amps) which is more recently maintained (5 months ago) but isn't official and has 62 open issues. Is this my best bet
Update: I installed snd_hda_macbookpro and I now see "Headphones" instead of "Dummy Output" but still no sound.
Update 2: I installed snd-hda-codec-cs8409 (by running make and make install in the repo's directory) and still "Headphones" is displayed and I hear no sound.
System info:
$ fastfetch 
                             ....              orange@orange-MacBookPro14-1
              .',:clooo:  .:looooo:.           ----------------------------
           .;looooooooc  .oooooooooo'          OS: Ubuntu noble 24.04 x86_64
        .;looooool:,''.  :ooooooooooc          Host: MacBookPro14,1 (1.0)
       ;looool;.         'oooooooooo,          Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-48-generic
      ;clool'             .cooooooc.  ,,       Uptime: 2 mins
         ...                ......  .:oo,      Packages: 1620 (dpkg), 10 (snap), 1 (brew)
  .;clol:,.                        .loooo'     Shell: bash 5.2.21
 :ooooooooo,                        'ooool     Display (Color LCD): 2560x1600 @ 60 Hz (as 1280x800) in 13" [Built-in]
'ooooooooooo.                        loooo.    DE: GNOME 46.0
'ooooooooool                         coooo.    WM: Mutter (Wayland)
 ,loooooooc.                        .loooo.    WM Theme: Yaru-dark
   .,;;;'.                          ;ooooc     Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3/4]
       ...                         ,ooool.     Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3/4]
    .cooooc.              ..',,'.  .cooo.      Font: Ubuntu Sans (11pt) [GTK2/3/4]
      ;ooooo:.           ;oooooooc.  :l.       Cursor: Yaru (24px)
       .coooooc,..      coooooooooo.           Terminal: GNOME Terminal 3.52.0
         .:ooooooolc:. .ooooooooooo'           Terminal Font: Ubuntu Sans Mono (13pt)
           .':loooooo;  ,oooooooooc            CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U (4) @ 3.60 GHz
               ..';::c'  .;loooo:'             GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 @ 1.00 GHz [Integrated]
                                               Memory: 2.54 GiB / 7.62 GiB (33%)
                                               Swap: 0 B / 4.00 GiB (0%)
                                               Disk (/): 11.24 GiB / 109.63 GiB (10%) - ext4
                                               Local IP (wlp2s0): 192.168.100.173/24
                                               Battery (bq20z451): 88% (6 hours, 49 mins remaining) [Discharging]
                                               Locale: en_US.UTF-8

                                                                       
                                                                       


We don't know what will work and what is the "best bet". Did you even try installing the drivers in the repositories you found? They work in many cases

@ArchismanPanigrahi I asked because I want this post to be a reference for best-practice for my situation. It is not trivial to go back to after trying to install a driver (without a clean reinstall).

I’m voting to close this question because, as the OP said in their answer, the issue is hardware-related.

@BeastOfCaerbannog I agree

I reinstalled macOS and sound is still not working. So this is probably a hardware issue.
